# JavaFX TableView change to other <Type>

Tags: types, javafx-2, tableview

I'm new to JavaFX, having only used Swing jTables previously, so please bear with me here.
I have a scene created in JavaFX, with a TableView. I've figured out how to use the ObservableList for populating data in the TableView (i.e. a list of Person objects) - but I'm struggling to find a way to re-use the same TableView to represent another Type of Objects (ie. Event objects)

Are they really locked to the first defined type, or how would one come about this?

I've considered creating multiple TableViews and then showing/hiding the ones I need, but couldn't find any feasible way to make this happen - any suggestions, solutions or any advice at all is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Supposedly a Person and an Event don't contain the same data - how do you plan to use the same tables, same columns etc. if the content is completely different? You probably need one TableView per type of content that you can show/hide as required.

Comment: I weren't planning on using the same layout, columns etc. - only the TableView as a place holder

Comment: I don't think it's meant to be used that way. You can create a Region (say an AnchorPane) to contain the TableView - and when you want to show something different: place the other TableView in that Region instead of the original one.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this myself, apparently the TableView  constructor does not need an explicit Type, so if none is specified, it will accept any object thrown at it - if only the columns are correctly set up.